# How to adjust text in textview next line for long text in android

Tags: android, textview, android-cardview

```xml
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_r2_4k"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_16sdp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_sub_title">
    
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_first_4k"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_first_camera_title_4k"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="asjdgbajshgdsahjGDHJASGDJHASGDJHASgdhjas"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_242424"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_20"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img_camera_first_4k"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/img_camera_first_4k" />
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_camera_first_4k"
                    android:layout_width="112dp"
                    android:layout_height="112dp"
                    android:contentDescription="TODO"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_rtwo_fourk"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ln_camera_r2_4k"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ln_camera_r2_4k"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img_camera_first_4k"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/img_camera_first_4k">
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/radio_cam_r2_4k"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:contentDescription="TODO"
                        android:src="@drawable/radio_button" />
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_checked_r2_4k"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:contentDescription="TODO"
                        android:src="@drawable/checked" />
                </RelativeLayout>
    
    
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is my xml I am trying to set text in textview for  less text size its coming fine but when i increase text size like long  string its not setting in textview properly its overlapping in view .

I want like when text is increase then it should set it in next line.

Currently it's coming

[image]

I want to set text next line if its long text .

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code might help you

Use `android:maxEms` to specify a maximum amount of characters in conjunction with `android:singleLine="false"`.

Comment: Thanks  but android:maxEms what i have to  add in this ?

Comment: That should be font size in int like 2 or 4 or 10 what ever you required. You can try putting different number as per your need.

Comment: but i want when we have  large device it should set in single line if text are adjustable in small device i want to set in two line

Comment: For that you need to create own custom textview which can be dynamically take ems size as per device

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to create something like this:

[image: Long Short Text]

I recommend you use Linearlayout and set its orientation to horizontal. Set the weight for your textview and your text should adjust depending on the device's screen size. So if the text is too long for the screen size of your device, it will create multiple lines. If it fits, it'll only create a single line. This is the code I used:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_r2_4k"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_sub_title">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_first_4k"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_first_camera_title_4k"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="short text"
        android:textColor="#242424"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_camera_first_4k"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cam_outline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ln_camera_r2_4k"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/radio_cam_r2_4k"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_check_confirm" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_checked_r2_4k"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_check_confirm" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```